# Add fork within an existing repo

Tags: git, github, repository, fork, clone

I have a repository on GitHub.com which contains some very useful files. These files act as a template and helper files for `Latex` code.
I rarely change these files because they are a template, but those who use them might have to make changes to them.

What I need is a way for those who use the files to create a `fork` into their own repository, make changes to their fork and push them, so that only their repository can see them.
The key: a fork INSIDE another repo.

Now, forks works not as being put into an existing repo but being beside it.
I really need it into the existing one.

Any clue of what I need to do?

The very, plain, solution is downloading the files as a zip, and unzip them into a plain folder in the repository. But this way they can't be updated.

Answer (score 2):

The `fork` equivalent within a repo, is called `branch`.
just submit your changes to a new branch, and no need to `push` these changes anywhere.

To repeat: there is *no* need to `push` your changes at all.

If you are concerned about having your submodule in a *dirty* state and you don't want to accidentally commit an updated submodule to your main repository, you can *ignore* changes in submodules:

```
[submodule "coolstuff"]
    path = coolstuff
    url = ...
    ignore = dirty
```

If you are concerned about accidentally `pushing` your changes, you can set the `push` url of your remote to something invalid:

```
$ git remote set-url origin --push /dev/null
```

which gives you:

```
$ git push
fatal: '/dev/null' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Aternatively, simply clone from a *read-only* URL.

Comment: That was not what I wanted, no. I have changed the question to express the problem better.